# Audio-only livestream that is web-linkable

Tags: streaming

We're currently using zoom for our audio livestreaming solution, but our member count is getting too big for a single zoom meeting. I'm looking for an alternative to hosting multiple zoom meetings simultaneously.

I'm looking for a livestreaming service that is:

1. Audio only

   - We only have an audio feed, and we are broadcasting from a place with limited but persistent data connectivity.
2. Can be accessed via weblink

   - Our audience is not IT-savvy, and will probably tune in via mobile. A direct web link to the stream would be the most fuss-free way to access the livestream.

The easier to set up, the better. Volume isn't that significant, I can expect a few dozens at most.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at [Icecast](https://icecast.org/) which is:

Icecast is a streaming media (audio/video) server which currently supports Ogg (Vorbis and Theora), Opus, WebM and MP3 streams.
It can be used to create an Internet radio station or a privately running jukebox and many things in between. It is very versatile in that new formats can be added relatively easily and supports open standards for communication and interaction.

Icecast is distributed under the GNU GPL, version 2.

An installer is available for Windows or source code for Linux.

### Mediaplayers that support Icecast streams

These media players are known to work with Icecast

- VLC  Linux/Unix, Windows, macOS, Android, iOS
- MPlayer  Linux/Unix, Windows, macOS
- Clementine Music Player  Linux/Unix, Windows, macOS
- Zinf (MP3, OGG Vorbis)   Linux/Unix, Windows
- XMMS (MP3, OGG Vorbis)   Linux/Unix
- Xine Linux/Unix
- foobar2000 (MP3, OGG Vorbis) Windows
- Winamp 2.x/5.x (MP3, OGG Vorbis) Windows
- FStream  iOS, macOS
- TuneIn Radio iOS, Android, Windows Phone, Blackberry
- Internet Radio Box   iOS
- StreamS HiFi Radio App   iOS, tvOS